# VB.NET Localization of strings

Tags: vb.net, localization, visual-studio-2017

I've been successful in using form.location.resx files to localize the strings associated with form controls. However, I don't see how to (safely!) add strings to the .resx file(s) and then access them for such things as message boxes.

If I try to add a string to the .resx file using Visual Studio (2017), I get a warning dialog pop-up telling me that this could corrupt the "project item" (form) or my changes could be lost if I change the associated form.

Also, if I use this method, would I need to manually add my strings to each language file separately?

Alternatively, I could create a bunch of Labels to the form with visible=false and then edit their strings in the .resx files and use something like:

```
msgbox(LabelSampleMessage.text,MsgBoxStyle.Information,LabelSampleMessage2.text)
```

But that seems like it would be massively inefficient.

Comment: Well folks, after reading the "preferred" methods, given that I only need a few messages, I elected to use my alternative method:

I created a new form that will not get displayed. I added a Label for each message that I need, then used: 

`FormMessages.LabelSampleMessage.Text, MsgBoxStyle.Information,FormMessages.LabelSampleTitle.Text)`

This works fine, and is easy to localize. Not sure how this impacts resources, but again - I don't need a huge number of strings.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows Forms, the best way to do this is to go into the Designer and set the Language property on the form.  This will create a formName.Designer.languagecode.resx file for you.  Then you just edit the Text properties of the controls.  The changes will go to the resx file for the language you're editing.  You can even have different layout and control spacing for each language (useful if a label is short in English but translates to something long in German).

For MessageBox messages, you do the same thing with the Resources.resx file.  Just put all the messages in your Resources and duplicate the resx file for each language.  Then use the Resource editor to translate the message in the other languages.  You can then look up the message using `My.Resources.Default.SomeMessageKey`

Comment: Thank you dwilliss!

So to clarify: for the MessageBox messages, I can add my strings to the existing langauge.resx files (ignoring the Visual Studio warning dialog)? But I will need to add the same message key to each of the language files manually. That is, VS won't replicate them from the "default" language as it does for the strings generated with controls created in the Designer.

Answer (score 0):

@David: Note that I'm the author of a commercial ".resx" localization program for VS (in the interest of full disclosure). Yes, dwilliss is correct, though the names he used are a little off. For Windows forms, you can't manually update the ".resx" files yourself (directly), hence the warning from VS (don't know why they did things this way - go figure). You won't get that warning for strings you put in "Resources.resx" however. Just manually add "Resources.[LangCode].resx" and update it on your own. You have to add the keys yourself (again, no warnings). You can then simply access each string via the static properties seen in the "code-behind" file "Resources.Designer.cs" (one static property exists for each string you add). These are what MSFT calls "strongly typed" resources. If you access, say, "YourApp.Properties.Resources.SomeMessage" for instance (from "Resources.Designer.cs"), it will be returned in whatever language is currently set in "System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture" (assuming that language's satellite assembly is installed of course). This is all a pain and highly error-prone for other reasons as well, hence the reason I wrote my program (shameless plug but MSFT's way does work, though it's very primitive for handling translation in general - a professional organization relying on an external translator will save a lot of problems and $ in the long run by using a 3rd-party translation program, not mine necessarily though it would be my tool of choice of course, but anything is better than handling it manually).

Comment: @David: For some reason I missed that you're using VB.NET (C# is just ingrained in my brain for .NET., since most people are now using it course, though I actually work with C++ most of the time these days). Anyway, the same thing applies in that environment IIRC though the mechanics (names, etc.). will obviously differ a little (it's been a very long time since I looked at it).